# Want to achieve split scroll effect same as given link

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, effect

https://herstoryjewels.com/collections/kaleido

in this there is a product image section which on scroll images are stacking but in opposite direction scroll this I want to incorporate into my website anyone is there who can help me in this situation. So please help me while developing this code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.